# Using AJAX to pass variable to PHP and get that variabel again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass values to a PHP script so i am using AJAX to pass those and that part works. But in the same function I want retrieve those values that I passed to the PHP script. The problem is I cannot retrieve any value from the PHP file. I have search high and low, but now come to you for answers. How can I store the variable passed on to the PHP script so that my ajax can retrieve it? My code is as follows:

This is my form :

```
<!-- file album.php -->
<html>
<head>

    <?PHP
      include ("conection/connect.php");
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jstbl/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function cekjumlah(tableID)
        {
            var hitung=document.getElementById(tableID).rows.length;
            var jumlah = hitung-1;
            document.getElementById("media").value=jumlah;
        }

    </script>

</head>
<title></title>
<body>

    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
        Jumlah Inputan : 
        <input type="text" id="media" name="media" size="5">
        <input type="text" id="data_barang" name="data_barang" size="60" onKeyPress="onEnterPenjualan(event);">
        <br><br>

        <table id="tabelimei" border="1">
            <tr id="Last">
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <div id="menu">
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="simpan" value="Simpan" onClick="cekjumlah('tabelimei')">
                <input onClick="deleteRow('DivTambah')" name="button" type="submit" value="Hapus" />
            </p>
            <p id="hasil">hasil</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my jquery :

```
function onEnterPenjualan(e){// => Digunakan untuk membaca karakter enter
    var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(key==13){// => Karakter enter dikenali sebagai angka 13
        $(function(){
        var data_barang = $("#data_barang").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ambildatabarang.php",
            data: "data_barang="+data_barang,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);  
            }
        });                   
        var nama = alert (data.$nama);
        var baris = document.getElementById("data_barang").value;
        var i = 1;
        var row = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'DivTambah' + i);
        row = '<tr>'+
              '<td>1</td>'+
              '<td><input name="cek[0]" id="cek" type="checkbox" size="10" /></td>'+
              '<td><input name="qty_penjualan[0]" type="text" id="qty_penjualan" value="1" size="10" required/></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="imei_penjualan[0]" id="imei_penjualan" size="60" value="'+baris+'" required/></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="nama_penjualan[0]" id="nama_penjualan" size="30" value = "'+nama+'"required/></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="hargajual_penjualan[0]" id="hargajual_penjualan" value="300000" size="15" required/></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="diskon_penjualan[0]" id="diskon_penjualan" size="15" value="0"/></td>'+
              '<td><input type="text" name="total_penjualan[0]" id="total_penjualan" size="15" value="300000" required/></td>'+
              '<td><button type="button" class="del">Del</button></td>'+
              '</tr>';
        $(row).insertBefore("#Last");
        var hapus = "";
        document.getElementById('data_barang').value=hapus;
        document.getElementById('data_barang').value.focus();
        i++;
    });

    $(".del").live('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

}}
```

And this is my PHP file :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['data_barang'])){    
      // Instructions if $_POST['value'] exist 
    include ("conection/koneksidb.php");
    $databarang = $_GET['data_barang'];
    $datalengkapbarang = mysql_query("SELECT i.id_imeibarang, jb.nama_jenisbarang, b.type_barang, b.hargajual_barang FROM jenisbarang jb, barang b, imeibarang i WHERE i.id_imeibarang='$databarang' and i.idbarang_imeibarang=b.id_barang and b.idjenis_barang=jb.id_jenisbarang");

    $angka = 1; 
    while($k = mysql_fetch_array($datalengkapbarang)){
        echo $no[$angka] = $angka;
        echo $imei[$angka]=$k['id_imeibarang'];
        echo $nama[$angka]=$k['nama_jenisbarang'].$k['type_barang'];
        echo $harga[$angka]=$k['hargajual_barang'];

        $angka = $angka+1;
    }  
} 
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors along the way? "It's not working" isn't sufficient to help you out most likely.

Comment: Ajax is ASYNCHRONOUS. You read the data BEFORE it comes back from the server! That is why you have the success callback! The logic that relies on the data needs to be called when the response is returned.

Comment: @Samsquanch : I passed value data_barang with ajax (ambildatabarang.php) to get data from database barang and It will query value id_barang, nama_barang, jenis_barang. And i wanna get again those variabels from query before, and take those variabel in jquery 'row'. Example variabel nama in row = '<td><input type="text" name="nama_penjualan[0]" id="nama_penjualan" size="30" value = "'+nama+'"required/></td>'+

Comment: @epascarello : So how i can get one by one variabels from my data in database after ajax done? i wanna insert those variable in row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to send the some data to php and get the result of the php file to javascript synchronously, this is what you need

```
function sendData (data1,data2)
{
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            else
                AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            if (AJAX)
            {
                AJAX.open("POST", "url.php", false);
                AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                AJAX.send("data1=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2);
                return AJAX.responseText;                                         
            } 
            else
                return null;
}
```

now, on your php file, you just get your data like this

```
$data1 = $_POST['data1'];
$data2 = $_POST['data2'];
```

once you work with the data in your php file, and then you `echo` the result, it is returned by the javascript function, so you just need to use it like this in your javascript file

```
var data_from_php = sendData(data1,data2);
```